# Looking for OCR for VB.NET (VS 2008 PRO)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ocr

Looking for a component, dll, etc, for OCR for a VB.NET program.  Using VS PRO 2008.

The source is a bunch of small png images, and I am just getting a price out of them.  Very simple.

Tried tessnet2, but could not get png to work.  Don't mind commercial, but not too expensive - maybe about $100.  Want something simple to use and preferably with support if needed.  This is for a commercial application.

Thank you!

Comment: What resolution are your images ?  Are they screen shots or actual scanned images ?  Is the font always the same ?  Can you post a couple of sample images as this would make it easier to make suggestions.

Comment: They are downloaded images of prices.  The font is always the same, very clear and distinct.  Sorry I can't post an example.  The stats on one of them is:size 66 x 31  Pixels (2.13), dpi 2.3 x 1.1 cm; 0.9 x 0.4 inches, colors 16,7 Millions   (24 BitsPerPixel), disk size 1.10 KB (1,127 Bytes).  The price is like "$ 1.75".  They are png files, background is transparent.

Comment: Is the point size, baseline and style also constant. If so,I have some C# code that that does a pretty good job but it is not something I want to post freely on SO. My experience is that commercial ocr engines will only get you 90 - 95%. It us difficult to be accurate without seeing some images first.  31pixels high shoud be enough to get reasonable results from ocr.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office 2003 onwards (Or Word 2003+) comes with something called Microsoft Office Document Imaging (MODI) Its a COM component you can use to perform ocr.

See this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/modi.aspx

And I also bumped into this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/10/01/Free-OCR-software_3F00_-You-may-already-have-it_2E002E002E00_.aspx

The downside of course would be needing office installed I think.

Comment: Thank you.  I am aware of that, but it says :Supported image formats are TIFF, multi-page TIFF, and BMP" - I need png.  Yes, I can convert, but need to keep as simple as possible, mainly due to speed of processing (the images are simple,but there could be many of them).

Answer (score 0):

Got tessnet2 to work with png.  png was not working because of the transparent background.  Made a second image with a background color contrasting the text color, and drew the original image on top of that.  The second image ocr'd perfectly.

Would still be interested in a commercial ocr not too expensive, but this works now.

Thank you for your replies!